# How to build a decorator that works on the final argument of multi-arity curried functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a functional library in JavaScript. I'm also using `lodash`.

What I've got so far, abstractly:

```
x = _.curry(function(property, data) {
  return data.get(property);
});
```

With this, you can do `x(1)(2)` and `x(1, 2)`, and everything works as expected.

Say I want to modify the function so that it `data` can be an array:

```
x = _.curry(function(property, data) {
  if (_.isArray(data)) {
    return _.map(data, x(property));
  } else {
    return item.get(property);
  }
});
```

Now that works great. But I've got 30+ functions. There's got to be a better way than manual `if (_.isArray(data)... else...` writing for each function. A decorator maybe?

```
decorate = function(func) {
  // return a curried func and handle the aforementioned _.isArray
}

x = decorate(function(property, data) {
  if (_.isArray(data)) {
    return _.map(data, x(property));
  } else {
    return item.get(property);
  }
});
```

I'm completely lost on how to write the decorate function: A function that can take arity 2 and arity 3 functions to decorate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you wrap the original function with one that maps array arguments, then you curry that wrapped version.

```
var decorate = function(func) {
    var mapIfArray = function(property, data) {
        if (_.isArray(data)) {
            return _.map(data, _.curry(func)(property));
        } else {
            return func(property, data);
        }
    }

    return _.curry(mapIfArray);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var undecorated = function(property, data) {
    return data.get(property);
}

var decorated = decorate(undecorated);
```

That's assuming all your undecorated functions are arity 2, with the possible array at the end.  If that's not the case, you'll either have to create different decorators for different arities, or do some sort of voodoo with the arguments object.

Comment: This is very helpful—thanks dude :)
I do have to wrap arity 3 functions, but I think you've gotten me on the right track. I'll try it out and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish but could something like this work? This is a bit hacky but idea is to pass the function from the outside.

```
x = _.curry(function(func, data) {
 return _.map(_.flatten([data]), func);
});
```

Comment: I thought of that, but didn't want to introduce loops when I didn't need any. Also, `_.isArray(data) ? data : [data]` would be faster than `_.flatten([data])` :)